# Задать html с текста

Tags: node.js, node-modules, handlebars, hbs

Мне нужно задать в hbs  html разметку но ту которую я беру с БД, мне нужно что бы:

```js
res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.hbs", 
        {
            article: "<b> 22 </b>"
        });
```

выполнился правильно, вместо жирного текста "**22**" мне выводит

> **22**

как правильно выйти из данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина по которой теги взяты за текст понятна, у тебя стоит

> {{ article }}

то что ты хочешь должно быть заключено в тройные скобки, типа:

> {{{ article }}}